# Blend for Visual Studio 2012 - No design view

Tags: visual-studio-2012, blend, blend-2012

I have a normal WPF MVVM-Light application, that I tried opening in Blend (first time I used Blend for Visual Studio 2012 on my Windows 8 machine).

However, I'm not able to open the Design View, which pretty much renders Blend useless.

One issue I read was that it happens when your application's Output Type is set to Console, which isn't the case for me. Anyone else seen this?

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Apparantly, Blend included in VS2012 only supports Windows 8 Apps.

However, there's a preview been released for Blend + Sketchflow that allows other platforms here :

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30702

Comment: Also, there's now a CTP available for VS2012's update 2, which includes Blend 2012, and support for WPF and Silverlight. Details here : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/01/30/announcing-visual-studio-2012-update-2-vs2012-2.aspx

Comment: Windows 8 Apps. Typical. Those idiots must think they work for Google Plus now. Thanks. More than a year later, that update is still not in the production version of VS2012.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be the default Blend behavior when Blend does not support the .NET framework version that a project is configured to target.  You can resolve this by opening the project in VS, opening the project properties(Alt-Enter), and changing the target framework to a supported version.  For example, as of my writing this, Blend does not support .NET 4.5.2.  You must convert it to 4.5.1 (c.f. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/934732/blend-for-visual-studio-2013-does-not-render-the-design-view-with-net-framework-4-5-2)