# How do you edit styles in WPF 4.5 under Windows 7?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, expression-blend, asp.net-4.5, blend-2012

I just realised that Blend for Visual Studio 2012 does not support WPF apps under W7.

Once I opened a window I can only see raw XAML.

I need to edit a style for a chart dataseries `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting`. I normally use Blend for these kind of tasks - because it pulls default styles from somewhere and gives it to you in a blink of an eye.

now I am stuck.. what would you guys do?

**P.S. here is nice summary** for future references: http://blendinsider.com/technical/available-now-blend-for-visual-studio-2012-2012-08-15/

*(scroll down to see the table what version supports what)*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blend for Visual Studio 2012 - No design view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084445/blend-for-visual-studio-2012-no-design-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Blend Preview that supports WPF apps.

- http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/jj154135
- [How can I design an animation with a WPF project in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874005/how-can-i-design-an-animation-with-a-wpf-project-in-visual-studio-2012)

Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 will have a released version of Blend which supports WPF...in the meantime use the preview one.

- http://www.microsoft.com/expression/