# Can't see design view on Blend 5 when .NET Framework is 4.5.1

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, blend

I'm developing a VS 2012 WPF project with C#, .NET Framework 4.5.1 and MvvmLight 5.1.1.0.

I have created the project on Visual Studio 2012 Premium Update 4. I have a design view for my `MainWindows.xaml` on VS but when I open it on Blend 5 for Visual Studio 2012, I get this:

[image]

I can't see design view and also, I can't add new elements to it.

If I change .NET Framework to 4, it works. I see the design view.

Any idea about how can I fix this problem? How can I 'install' .NET Framework 4.5.1 on Blend 5 for Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084445/blend-for-visual-studio-2012-no-design-view

Comment: The assembly (version 4.5.1) needed for the design view might not be in the GAC and therefore Blend cannot use them.

Comment: Thanks. What assembly? How can I add it to GAC?